# Intersecção entre objetos de dois arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, node.js

Preciso fazer a interseção de objetos dentro de dois arrays e exibir a igualdade entre eles.

Ex:

```
const sociosCedente =  [{
    nome: 'maria ',
    nome: 'Joao',
    nome: 'henrique',
    nome: 'anderson',
    nome: 'carol'
}];

const sociosSacado = [{
    nome:'eduardo',
    nome:'anderson',
    nome:'carol'
}];

Reposta: 'Anderson, 'Carol'
```

Tentei:

```js
const sociosCedente = [{
  nome: 'maria ',
  nome: 'Joao',
  nome: 'henrique',
  nome: 'anderson',
  nome: 'carol'
}];

const sociosSacado = [{
  nome: 'eduardo',
  nome: 'anderson',
  nome: 'carol'
}];

const intersection = sociosCedente.filter(item1 => sociosSacado.some(item2 => item1.nome === item2.nome))

console.log(intersection);
```

Porém, só retorna o ultimo objeto.

Comment: uma forma de fazer seria usando o includes, você poderia checar se dentro do array existe a string e salvar ela em um novo array caso exista, e depois retorna esse novo array.

Comment: Mas essa estrutura de dados não deveria ser utilizada. A estrutura é equivocada para o que pretende, pois trata-se dum array cujo o único elemento é um array associativo. Arrays associativo tem como características a univocidade das chaves, ou seja as **chaves devem ser únicas**. Quando declara mais de uma vez a chave `nome` dentro do objeto o último valor da chave é sobrescrito pelo valor recém declarado.

Comment: Na verdade, esta estrutura de dados é o que retorna de uma api que estou consultando.

Comment: faça `console.log(sociosCedente)` e `console.log(sociosSacado)` e então faça a conferencia, pois o que está na pergunta é uma impossibilidade. Pode comprovar o que dig aqui: https://ideone.com/ktsFA4

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu votei pra fechar como erro de digitação com base no que você comentou. Mas acho que a ideia do AP seria vários objetos com `nome`, porque da forma como está não faz sentido mesmo.

Comment: @CmteCardeal: Realmente não faz sentido, e o que me intriga é AP alegar ter recebido essa estrutura de uma API. Provavelmente o que foi recebido é um texto representando um JSON malformado o que poderia ser solucionado com reparo ou substituição da API(ou processamento do texto, mas pouco indicado). Mas até o AP esclarecer o que temos é apenas o que está escrito.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Está retornando apenas o primeiro objeto encontrado porque os objetos que vc está comparando tem nomes de propriedades repetidas, e isso dá gera conflito, separe os nomes em objetos diferentes, segue um exemplo:

```js
const sociosCedente = [{
    nome: 'Maria'
  },
  {
    nome: 'João'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Henrique'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Anderson'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Carol'
  },
]

const sociosSacado = [{
    nome: 'Eduardo'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Anderson'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Carol'
  },
]

const intersection = sociosCedente.filter((item1) =>
  sociosSacado.some((item2) => item1.nome === item2.nome)
)

console.log(intersection)
```